Confused about IPv6 link local addreses
Here's what the RFC says about link local IPv6 addresses:
   |   10     |
   |  bits    |         54 bits         |          64 bits           |
   +----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
   |1111111010|           0             |       interface ID         |
   +----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+

so the global routing prefix part of the address is fixed so the first 3 segments are fixed at 1111 1110 10XX which can span from
1111 1110 1000 - 0xFE8
to
1111 1110 1011 - 0xFEB
with the 54 bit subnet fixed at 0.
Then why is Linux marking fe91::1/64 and fe81::1/64 as link local?
Here's how it looks on Linux:
inet6 fe91::1/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe81::1/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::1d76:2a9f:e6fd:325c/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::212:11ff:feab:cd00/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


The entire fe80::/10, i.e. based on the initial 10 bits, is classified as "link-local" as per section 2.4 of the same RFC.
2.4.  Address Type Identification

   The type of an IPv6 address is identified by the high-order bits of
   the address, as follows:

      Address type         Binary prefix        IPv6 notation   Section
      ------------         -------------        -------------   -------
      Unspecified          00...0  (128 bits)   ::/128          2.5.2
      Loopback             00...1  (128 bits)   ::1/128         2.5.3
      Multicast            11111111             FF00::/8        2.7
      Link-Local unicast   1111111010           FE80::/10       2.5.6
      Global Unicast       (everything else)

(Earlier revisions, such as RFC 3513, also had a "Site-Local" fec0::/10 in which the subnet number was not fixed to 0.)
"Standard" link-local addresses have 0 as the remainder, making it effectively fe80::/64 in practice, but this doesn't change that the whole /10 is designated link-local (and is listed in the special use address registry as allocated for this purpose).

Thanks for the clarification. I'm trying to wrap my head around this so could you expand on what you mean by the 'entire'  fe80::/10 being classified as link local? Do you mean ALL address that could be derived after keeping the first ten bits fixed at 1111-1110-10 ? I'm looking at a definitive meaning/reference for the 'whole' part above

Yes, that's what the RFC says. I've already included a table copied directly from the RFC and it gives you the prefix both in binary notation and in CIDR notation, and I've also included a link to the address assignment table at IANA. I don't know what other reference you're expecting.

I mean for the other bits. Based on this, all addresses from FE80:: to FEBF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF are apparently classified as link local but this is not very clear from the RFC since it mentions the other bits (outside of the initial 10 bits) to be explicitly zero. Or perhaps I haven't seen the part or are they deliberately ambiguous to allow for a level of flexibility?
